# Mixing Boost.Python with third party bindings

Tags: c++, boost-python

Our application provides python bindings through [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html). However, many API methods use types defined by third-party libraries: one example is [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org), another is [Qt](http://qt.io/).

For some of these libraries, third-party bindings are sometimes available: for Eigen, I found [minieigen](https://github.com/eudoxos/minieigen); for Qt, [PySide2](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python) is available.

Generally, how would I go about leveraging these bindings without writing my own converters for each type? For example, consider the following:

```
class Test
{
public:
    static double test(const Eigen::Vector3d& vector)
    {
        return vector.norm(); //just an example
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    scope classScope = class_<Test>("Test", no_init)
            .def("test", &Test::test)
            .staticmethod("test")
    ;
}
```

Wrapped like this, the code obviously does not work:

```
>>> from test import Test
>>> import minieigen
>>> Test.test(minieigen.Vector3(0, 1, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Test.test(Vector3)
did not match C++ signature:
    test(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>)
```

I understand that the problem is that the Boost.Python runtime is not informed about the types wrapped by minieigen, so I must provide some kind of "glue code". It seems like Shiboken (for PySide2) provides an API just for this ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542778/import-classes-from-pyside-inside-of-a-boost-python-module) deals with that, but it is still confusing to me); however, it does not seem like minieigen has anything like that.

In the past, I found a promising piece of code, by which the author would wrap/unwrap the underlying C++ pointers from PyObject's, however I am not able to find it again...

I would appreciate a similar procedure to save the work of wrapping every single third-party type used in our program.